# ./ in Clojure (qualified symbol?)

Tags: compiler-construction, clojure, functional-programming, qualified-name

I'm currently implementing a different language ([Shen](http://www.shenlanguage.org)) in Clojure.

Shen has a symbol "./" but in Clojure this is interpreted before evaluation and thus results in an error.
I do not need "./" inside the macro which is compiling this function to Clojure code.

Is there a way to ignore this?
I think it is interpreted as an qualified symbol but without a name, since replacing it by a/ or xyz/ results in the same error messages.

My current macro is as simple as

```
(defmacro kl/trap-error [x [y z r]] `(try ~x (catch Exception '~z ~r)))
```

But when I call it with Shen code the following happens:

```
kl=> (trap-error (/ 1 0) (./ E (error-to-string E)
RuntimeException Invalid token: ./  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:156)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: E in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: E in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:89)
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In CL you can use |./|, I don't know if it works for Clojure.

Comment: As far as I know, you would need a custom reader to do this in Clojure, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @danlei: But as far as I know Clojure doesn't have a standard way to define a reader macro, you have to [hack a bit](http://briancarper.net/blog/449/clojure-reader-macros) and that's not really appreciated.

Comment: Daimrod, yes, that's what I meant when I wrote *custom reader*: a dedicated Shen reader, written from scratch.

Comment: Apart from being appreciated or not, maybe one could get something like CL's standard syntax multiple escape character to work in Clojure with http://github.com/klutometis/reader-macros, but I didn't really take a closer look at it. (A custom reader would surely be the preferred solution, but still this might be useful at least for testing purposes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without modifying the Clojure reader (a privilege which is not given to Clojure programmers). Your statement "Shen has a symbol `./` but in Clojure this is interpreted before evaluation and thus results in an error" is incorrect, though - no interpretation or evaluation goes on at all, because the reader sees these characters and can't even figure out what data type they should be.

- Are they a list? Nope, no parens.
- Are they a string? Nope, no quotes.
- Are they a symbol? Nope, there would be a namespace but no name.
- ...many more cases like this...
- I give up, this isn't a data structure that represents valid Clojure code.

Comment: So writing Shen code in the Clojure REPL is not possible, right? Only reading files and replacing "./" before using e.g. read-string...

Comment: Well. clojure.main/repl allows you to specify a function that will be used for reading instead of the built-in. So for the specific case of writing it on the repl, you can probably do just fine with a little work. But requiring files has no such hook, so I don't think there's anything you can do in the general case.

Comment: Thank you. I might try to write a "Shen REPL" that can read this. For now I go with only reading Shen files and replace the /. by lambda before the evaluation.